# variable declaration is not working in eval in react render function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

this works in normal javascript code and variable is declared in outer scope.

```
eval("var a = 10"); 
console.log(b)
```

But when I do the same in the react render function, it doesn't work.
eval(a+b) is working in react when `a` and `b` are declared in the outer scope.

Comment: Share to us your code

Comment: Why would you need eval anyway? That's an absurdly huge code smell

Comment: I completely understand and aware of the eval side effects and issues. Need eval for a particular use case where an expression is coming from the server which I need to evaluate.

Comment: not everyone is dev for web app, in the context of an secure app window (nwjs,electron), eval to execute user scripts is very interesting, and user cant hack wihout devtool.

Comment: maybe cause of strict mode? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#simplifying_variable_uses

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

let a = "10";
let plus = '+'
let b = "5";

export default class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View>
          <Text>{eval(a + plus + b)}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Gus Nando, Thank for putting your effort and sharing the above code. As I said in the question evaluation of an expression in eval works. But a new variable declaration doesn't.

Comment: ah sorry about that, something like this? 
var a = 1;
var name = 'a = 10';

<Text>{eval(name)}</Text> // 10